# 2 password reset e-mails in Django every time I try to reset a password

Tags: python, django, passwords

I am a beginner in Django and i have been following an online tutorial to build a web application. I had been trying to add the password reset functionality to the application for the past few days. I set up a google app password and finally got the password reset to work. But now, every time i try to reset a password, i receive 2 password reset emails on my email account. I have reset the password successfully a few times but i continue to receive two emails every time i try to reset a password. I tried to look for answers online but couldn't find anything. I have also cross-checked my code with the tutorial. Here are some code snippets that might be relevant:

Project settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
        path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
        path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
        path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'),
             name='password_reset'),
        path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
        path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
        path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
            template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
        path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
        path('', include('blog.urls')),
    ]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

PS: This is my first question on StackOverflow. Please let me know if i can improve it in any way.

Comment: from where do you importing the `auth_views` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have edited the question to display all imports

Comment: Great. Since you are using the built-in views, I don't think the issue belongs to the code-base. Try to use some other email providers such as [Send Grid](https://sendgrid.com/), [Mail Gun](https://www.mailgun.com/) etc.

Comment: @SultanSinghAtwal and also make sure that there is only 1 request for password reset url.

Comment: it's maybe caused by your template codes, for example the form may has been send twice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, but the answer is really simple:

I bet you have 2 Django accounts which use the same mail address. In my case I have a normal user account but I'm also the administrator of Django and use the same mail address for the admin account too. :)

Django loops through all accounts and send a mail to every user where the mail address matches.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but when I search users by that email address, there is only one user, don't know what's going on :(

Answer (score 0):

I override class PasswordResetView

Correct

```
class UserPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    """."""

    def form_valid(self, form):
        r429 = ratelimit.consume_or_429(
            self.request,
            action="reset_password_email",
            key=form.cleaned_data["email"].lower(),
        )
        if r429:
            return r429
        form.save(self.request)
        signals.password_reset.send(
            sender=self.__class__,
            request=self.request,
            email=form.cleaned_data["email"].lower(),
        )
        return super(PasswordResetView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The first time I used return: `return super().form_valid(form)`
What caused the message to be sent twice